# Linux Kernel init fails in encrypted filesystem

Tags: linux, encryption, linux-kernel, filesystems, boot

I am trying to make a linux os with encrypted filesystem for the whole OS (boot,kernel,root,...)

I modified EXT4 filesystem's read and write functions. after running a lot of tests <s>everything</s> read and write work fine.

EDIT:

> my change is a simple XOR to file contents.
>
> my tests include reading/writing text files, tar archive
> creation/deletion, sound and videofile creation/copying/deletion and
> some stress tests.

```
this is dmesg says when trying to run a binary:

traps: a.out[2765] trap invalid opcode ip:400e73 sp:7ffc9f3d6f10 error:0 in a.out[400000+b4000]
```

next step was to boot a simple linux based OS on this encrypted filesystem,  I modified GRUB 2 bootloader so it cat boot the kernel from encrypted disk.
then I faced this problem:

- grub can load linux kernel and kernel boots, but when it tries to run the init proccess I get kernel panic with the message: "init Not tained".

I can see from previous messages that filesystem is loaded by kernel and it is actually reading init file but refuses to run init.

my question is: is kernel reading init file in any other way than using standard read system call? is there something I am doing wrong here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT:

> now the question is:
>
> how can I decrypt the data that kernel uses by mapping memory?

Comment: grub can handle out-of-the-box lvm on luks, even /boot; use GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK; read https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB for whole explanation

Comment: @gengisdave the problem is not the grub. it is working and loads kernel. the problem is kernel does not run the init. and my encryption method is a simple bitwise to file contents. I did not use any standard disk encryption method.

Comment: So if my understanding is correct, you can launch manually any apps from encrypted FS, but when you start a kernel with encrypted root it fails to launch init?

Comment: @AlexHoppus yes I tested some binary files in an encrypted filesystem mounted with modified ext4 module(my systems filesystem is btrfs). and they were working

Comment: Have you tried with this particular init binary? And what is the reason of killing, can you see this in logs?

Comment: @AlexHoppus no I have also tested with 'init=/bin/ash' the only thing I see in kernel log is "init Not tained" (or with init=ash, ash Not tained). also first few characters of binary init are correct. (I just printed them out! ).

Comment: @AlexHoppus It appears that the problem is with some binary files can not run inside of encrypted filesystem! if I link them static I get: 'illegal instruction' and if I link them dynamic I get an error about glibc. 
so any idea?

Comment: So any file with dynamic linking gives this?

Comment: @AlexHoppus yes and also any binary file gives the error. not scripts. I was testing it wrong. any binaries have problem. so it is not using normal read system call for binaries.

Comment: I think you could post more details about your experiments now

Answer (score 2):

The kernel will map the `init` binary to memory (i.e, using `mmap()`) to execute it. If you have only tested `read()`, this is quite possibly where your filesystem is failing.

Comment: actually, the read stands behind mmap (it will be invoked via page_fault)

Comment: @duskwuff as Alex Hoppus said I also think read is behind mmap.

Comment: @duskwuff thanks for answering  can you show me some information about this subject(mmap()) and how it is done? some online resources or books would be perfect. actually reading some stuff I think as  Alex Hoppus said, mmap actually causes a normal read system call (am I wrong?) but I am really interested in how memory mapping works.

Comment: @duskwuff it appears that I was wrong. kernel is not using normal read for binary files. running scripts is ok from my filesystem but I get illegal instruction when I am trying to run a binary.

Comment: @duskwuff mmap just creates virtual mappings in this case, so it has nothing common with actual data manipulations, correct me if i'am wrong.